# TextMate New File Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Is there a keyboard shortcut in TextMate to create a new, blank file in a project? Basically, it would do the same thing as clicking the new file + icon at the bottom of the Project Drawer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For TextMate 2, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> will open a new file. Saving it will launch the new file dialog.

For TextMate, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will launch the new file dialog, when you're in a project.

Before doing either, you may chose where to create the new file using the keyboard arrows and navigating through the directory tree. Use the shortcut when you are in the directory where you want the file to be created.

Comment: ps. by default, the directory selected is based on the location within the project directory of the currently shown/opened file.